# Combine multiple event logs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to export multiple event logs from windows. The export of one event log works fine but when I try to combine them I have a problem: the file size is good but the number of events is not. (The size of log.evt is the sum of the log files but when I open it with event viewer the number of events is the one from application log)

```
void Msw::create_error_log() {
    std::thread application_worker(create_application_log);
    std::thread security_worker(create_security_log);
    std::thread setup_worker(create_setup_log);
    std::thread system_worker(create_system_log);

    if (application_worker.joinable() && security_worker.joinable() && setup_worker.joinable() && system_worker.joinable()) {
        application_worker.join();
        security_worker.join();
        setup_worker.join();
        system_worker.join();
    }

    std::ifstream application_file("application-log.evt", std::ios_base::binary);
    std::ifstream security_file("security-log.evt", std::ios_base::binary);
    std::ifstream setup_file("setup-log.evt", std::ios_base::binary);
    std::ifstream system_file("system-log.evt", std::ios_base::binary);

    std::ofstream full_log("log.evt", std::ios_base::binary);

    full_log << application_file.rdbuf() << setup_file.rdbuf() << system_file.rdbuf() << security_file.rdbuf();

}


void Msw::create_application_log() {
    HANDLE handle = OpenEventLog(NULL, "Application");
    BackupEventLog(handle, "application-log.evt");
}

void Msw::create_security_log() {
    HANDLE handle = OpenEventLog(NULL, "Security");
    BackupEventLog(handle, "security-log.evt");
}

void Msw::create_setup_log() {
    HANDLE handle = OpenEventLog(NULL, "Setup");
    BackupEventLog(handle, "setup-log.evt");
}

void Msw::create_system_log() {
    HANDLE handle = OpenEventLog(NULL, "System");
    BackupEventLog(handle, "system-log.evt");
}
```

Comment: _"the file size is good but the number of events is not"_ What exactly does that mean? In which way the number of events _isn't good_?

Comment: My guess is that the binary format of the event log files aren't such that they support plain concatenation. You probably need to actually parse out the events themselves and append to the "full" log. And aren't there any WINAPI functions that could help you to create a combined event log file?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The size of log.evt is the sum of the log files but when I open it with event viewer the number of events is the one from application log.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude from what I've read in the documentation there is only that function that backups only one event log.

Comment: @Robert-NicolaeSolca Please [edit] your question and add that symptom: _"The size of log.evt is the sum of the log files but when I open it with event viewer the number of events is the one from application log."_

Comment: If you opened notepad.exe and mspaint.exe and concatenated the binaries into a single file, would you expect the result to be a text editor with graphics support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by using [`EvtExportLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtexportlog).

```
void Msw::create_error_log() {
    LPWSTR pQuery = L"<QueryList>"
        L"  <Query Id='0'>"
        L"    <Select Path='Application'>*</Select>"
        L"  </Query>"
        L"  <Query Id='1'>"
        L"    <Select Path='System'>*</Select>"
        L"  </Query>"
        L"  <Query Id='2'>"
        L"    <Select Path='Setup'>*</Select>"
        L"  </Query>"
        L"</QueryList>";

    EvtExportLog(NULL, NULL, pQuery, L"log.evt", EvtExportLogChannelPath);
}
```